# Spring JMS Template sending invalid messages

Tags: java, spring, marshalling, spring-jms

I'm having an issue using Spring JMSTemplate to marshall and send JMS messages. Everything gets sent correctly, but when I try to view the messages in the queue it appears that the body text of the message is all garbled. I'm not sure where in my setup something might be wrong...I've sent messages using the same method I'm currently using before. Has anyone see this before?

This is a snippet of how the message body looks after it's sent:
`00000000:  3c3f  786d  6c20  7665  7273  696f  6e3d  2231  .?xml version."1
00000010:  2e30  2220  656e  636f  6469  6e67  3d22  5554  .0" encoding."UT
00000020:  462d  3822  2073  7461  6e64  616c  6f6e  653d  F.8" standalone.
00000030:  2279  6573  223f  3e3c  7072  6f64  7563  7445  "yes"?..productE`

I have the template and marshaller set up like this:

```
<!-- Non-pooled ConnectionFactory, don't use directly -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jmsFactory" jndi-name="${jms.connectionFactory}"/>

<!-- JMS Destinations -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="emfTopic" jndi-name="${emf.topic.jndiPath}"/>

<!-- JMS Template for sending JMS Messages -->
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="messageConverter"/>
</bean>

<!-- A converter that marshalls/unmarshalls XML messages -->
<bean id ="messageConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
</bean>

<!-- JAXB Marshaller for JMS Messages -->
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>...`
```

And I am sending the messages like this:
`EmfMessagePostProcessor postProcess =    new EmfMessagePostProcessor(true, hasId);`

```
//Convert the message, set properties, then send
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(this.emfTopic, theMessage, postProcess);`
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the message that you are sending out, to check whether there is any relationship between the two.

Comment: You don't provide enough detail about the most important bit. What is the `targetType` of your marshaller? Note that `MarshallingMessageConverter`is using bytes by default so your xml document is sent as a `BytesMessage`. Set  the `targetType` to text if you want to send the XML as is (in a `TextMessage`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stéphane's comment is where the issue was. I wasn't explicitly setting the targetType to be a TextMessage, so it was sending as a byteMessage since that is the default. Changing the targetType fixed the issue.